# How to increase concurrent requests in ASP.NET Core Web API hosted on IIS 10

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-core-webapi

I have hosted a ASP.NET Core Web API under IIS 10. But clients complains that they receive timeout errors. They sent around 200 requests per second to our API.

How can I get rid of the timeout error and increase number of concurrent requests (parallel requests) for our API?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Write better code? There's not a request limit you are hitting here, it's that your requests are taking too long to complete. Either make them faster and use less resource, or add more hardware.

Comment: 1. Use a performance profiler to analyze further why timeout occurs. That's how usually bottlenecks are determined. The goal is to set up a baseline on how quickly a response should be generated and how large the maximum timeout setting(s) should be set. 2. If the time required to generate a response might sometimes go far beyond a moderate value, you need to redesign the API surface and embrace the asynchronous pattern. Frameworks like SignalR are for that.

Comment: In IIS, even if you increase the idle timeout, the underlying problem of your slow requests still exists. The most direct way is to optimize your code and database queries to ensure that your code and database queries are efficient to reduce response time. Use asynchronous operations in your code to make more efficient use of server resources. Or you consider using a load balancer in front of your application to balance traffic and increase concurrent processing.